# Using parallel processes to speed up an interative bash loop, but I need to create an associative array inside the loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

Using Bash, I have an indexed array that represents a list of files:

```
a=("1.json" "2.json" "3.json" ... "5309.json")
```

I am parsing two data fields from those JSON files into two associative arrays:

```bash
declare -A idArr
declare -A valueArr

for i in "${a[@]}"; do
    jqId="$(jq -M ".fileId" <"${i}")"
    jqValue="$(jq -M ".value" <"${i}")"
    # If there are already items in the associative array, add the new items separated by a newline
    idArr[${i}]="${idArr[${i}]}${idArr[${i}]:+$'\n'}${jqId}"
    valueArr[${jqId}]="${valueArr[${jqId}]}${valueArr[${jqId}]:+$'\n'}${jqValue}"
done
```

Since I'm iterating through one file at a time, it takes a considerable amount of time to process all the files. I require the associative arrays created within the loop to persist beyond its scope, even after the loop has finished.

Is there a method, such as using `parallel` processing or any other approach, that would allow me to concurrently process multiple array items and still enable them to contribute data to the associative arrays?

Comment: Shell scripts tend to have limitations in the ways data can be exchanged between a parent process and its children.  The workarounds I've seen most often for this use case involve data storage that's external to the parent/child processes, and can handle simultaneous writes.  The child processes write their results to per-child files in a subdirectory; or they append rows to a table in a SQL database; or they write keys to a key/value store like Redis.  When the children are done, the parent reads the results from the data store and assembles them into the required data structures.

Comment: Or in other words, shells don't tend to support threads with shared memory. Between processes, you could also use pipes from the children to the parent, but shells also tend to have a hard time waiting for data from multiple fds at the same time (i.e. with the `select()` system call or such, though AFAIK zsh does have support for it). Hence writing the assignments out to a file or several and reading them back from the parent might make most sense. Or consider using another programming language, one where you can handle the JSON directly instead of calling another process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's likely slow here is that you're running two `jq`s per file and forking a process and executing `jq`  in it is likely orders of magnitude more work than processing a small json file.

```
read0() { IFS= read -rd '' "$@"; }
add_line() {
  typeset -n _var="$1"
  _var+=${_var:+$'\n'}$2
}
shopt -s extglob failglob lastpipe
set -o pipefail

typeset -A idArr valueArr

jq -j '[input_filename, .fileId, .value] |
       map(gsub("\u0000"; "") + "\u0000") | add
      ' -- +([0123456789]).json |
  while read0 file && read0 id && read0 value; do
    add_line "idArr[$file]"    "$id"
    add_line "valueArr[$file]" "$var"
  done
```

Would run `jq` only once. `jq` prints the filename, id and value (stripped of their NULs if any) NUL-delimited which bash reads in a loop in parallel.

**Important note**: do **not** call that `add_line` with arbitrary  file names as that would be a command injection vulnerability as `typeset -n` is a bit of an `eval` in disguise. For instance, if you used `*.json` in place of that `+([0123456789]).json`, and there was a file called `$(reboot).json`, that would reboot!

In current versions of bash, that can be worked around by using single quotes instead of double-quotes around the `idArr[$file]`, `valueArr[$file]`, but that may not be future-proof as future versions of bash might decide  to no longer do those expansions upon nameref dereferencing to avoid this kind of vulnerability.

Or you could remove those vulnerabilities by doing away with those mis-designed namerefs and using `eval` explicitly:

```
add_line() {
  eval "$1+=\${$1:+\$'\\n'}\$2"
}
```

And make sure to call it as:

```
    add_line 'idArr[$file]'    "$id"
    add_line 'valueArr[$file]' "$var"
```

Then you can use `*.json` or `"${a[@]}"` without the need to do some sanitisation¹.

If you run into a "argument list too long" error, replace `jq ... +([0123456789]).json` with `printf '%s\0' +([0123456789]).json | xargs -r0 jq ...`.

While you may be tempted to also use GNU `xargs`' `-P` to run some of those `jq`s in parallel, I would advise against it as `xargs` doesn't guarantee the serialisation of the output of the commands so the outputs of the individual `jq`s would likely end-up intertwined. GNU `parallel` does but also has a large overhead compared to something as simple as parsing a (presumably) short JSON file so may not add much benefit.

---

<sup>¹ Well, `jq` treats `-` as meaning stdin, so strictly speaking, if there is file named like that in your `$a` array (or the expansion of a `*` glob instead of `*.json`), you'd need to transform it to `./-`.</sup>